# .Net Mixed code - <Module>..ctor called failfast

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I maintain a mixed code dll (c# and c++ managed an unmanaged).
It works well on many platforms.

I started seeing the following stack trace in the application event-viewer:

```
at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
at <Module>.()
at <Module>..cctor()
```

When decompiling the dll, the  is huge with a lot of static functions and variables, but I can't find cctor.
I can't seem to find any helpful information.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation the cause was found to be a software from Dynatrace.
When this software was uninstalled, and machine was rebooted, all worked fine.

I guess it injects some code into our software which causes it to crash. We didn't go any further to investigate what exactly is going on in the instructions level.
Hope this helps to anyone in the future.

Comment: I am a Software Engineer at Dynatrace and I can share that we have seen this kind of behavior in conjunction with an Obfuscation tool "ConfuserEx". It has the capability to prevent "profilers" (which the Dynatrace .NET Agent is) to work. The config option for it is documented here: https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/wiki/Anti-Debug-Protection

Our suggestion in this case is to not use the "AntiDebug" option in ConfuserEx when obfuscating assemblies. Then the Dynatrace Agent will happily serve again :).

Comment: We found that the following env vars were enabled: COR_ENABLE_PROFILING=1 (and maybe COR_PROFILER=<some_id>). Once removed - everything started working fine.